# Differential equation of kepler orbit numerical solution in python?

Tags: python, differential-equations

So, I'm trying to write a code that solves the (what we called) differential equation of an orbit in the kepler potential V(r)=-1/r

when you do the math you get a differential equation that looks like this:

d^2u/d(fi)^2 + u - m/M^2=0

[image: Differential equation image]

where u=1/r
and we are ultimately looking for r(fi)

and now i tried to solve it using the numerical method, first i said du/dfi=y
then definig a function (i took some arbitrary M and m)

```
 def func(y,fi): 
    m=4
    M=5
    return [y[1],m/M^2-y[0]]$
```

and imported from     scipy.integrate import odeint
and then put in

```
 ts = np.linspace(0,15,150)
 ys = odeint(func, y0, ts)
```

now this gets me an array of 150 arrays of two numbers
and i don't really understand what dodes the first number mean and what does the second number mean is is

```
ys=[fi,u(fi)]
```

or something else?

Comment: Did you try reading `help(odeint)`?

Comment: I did, but unfortunately still don't quite get it :/

Comment: "_Returns ... array containing **the value of y** for each **desired time in t**, with the initial value `y0` in the first row._"

Comment: so the result is (t,y(t)) and I'm trying to get u(t)?

Answer (score 0):

The state for your order one system is `[value, derivative]`. The result of the integration is a list of state pairs of the same type.